# Find all github repositories based on a specific keyword

Tags: github-api

I am trying to find all repos based on a keyword 'TERRAGRUNT_VERSION' using github search api and its returning the below error. Am I missing something in the url?
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-repositories

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 2)
```

Code:

```
import requests


token = "access_token=" + "23456789087" 
base_api_url = 'https://api.github.com/'
search_final_url = base_api_url + 'search/repositories?q=TERRAGRUNT_VERSIONin:env/Makefile' + '&' + token       

try:
  response = requests.get(search_final_url).json()
  for item in response['items']:
     repo_name = item['name']
     print(repo_name)  
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

The issue is I'm getting a 400 response.
I tried the below

```
response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=TERRAGRUNT_VERSIONin:env/Makefile&access_token=456744")
print(response)

Output:
<Response [400]>
{'message': 'Must specify access token via Authorization header. https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param', 'documentation_url': 'https://docs.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-in-a-header'}
```

Comment: Well, so if it was not a `/`, can you show the response that you get from this search ?

Comment: I updated the question. I think i'm getting json decode error because the response body is empty. any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you have to pass `access_token` not as the url param but through the request header

If you try to search your link with browser, you would get the answer

```json
{
  "message": "Must specify access token via Authorization header. https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-in-a-header"
}
```

Full description is on the [link](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param) from response

Comment: It works after I passed the accesstoken as the request header. 

response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=TERRAGRUNT_VERSIONin:env/Makefile",   
headers={'Authorization': '46788'})

Comment: So, if we solved your problem you can accept the answer ;)